# Send Tweet from Apple Watch

Tags: swift2, watchkit, apple-watch, twitter-fabric

I would like to allow the user to send a tweet from the Apple Watch. Is there anything built in to the Apple SDK to allow this like there is on the iPhone, or is it possible using Fabric from Twitter?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your watchOS App you can send a Message with the text which should be tweeted. In your class on the iPhone app, which should handle the message, you send the tweet with the REST API (with [this](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update) url).